# Nscell Size Not Increasing With Row Height During Text Edit

Tags: cocoa, height, row, cell, nstableview

My NSTableView has variable height rows. The rows correctly resize after an edit of a cell has been completed, and during/after resizing the column/table. The Row also correctly resizes while a user is typing into the text cell.

However, the cell itself does NOT resize during editing to match the height of the row. Does anyone have any ideas on this? In [this screenshot](http://i1136.photobucket.com/albums/n487/ArrMiHardies/Snapbucket/ScreenShot2011-09-04at12746PM.png) one end-edit has occurred already (which is why the text area is larger than 1 line) but there is currently enough text in the cell to account for about 5 lines, thus the height of the row is not matching what should be displayed.

Comment: Screenshot: http://i1136.photobucket.com/albums/n487/ArrMiHardies/Snapbucket/ScreenShot2011-09-04at12746PM.png

Answer (score 1):

Both the textview and the cell have to have their autoresize set if you want them to automatically scale.

It looks like the cells in the `Tag Name` column are properly set to resize but that either the cell or the textview in the `value` column has not been. Check the sittings in Interface Builder.

Comment: The cells in the value column are created programmatically since their types can change based on what type of value they are to display. How would I set autoresizing on these programmatically? The apple docs dont specify any methods for doing so on the cell object and the textview object has setAutoresizesSubview, which alone doesn't seem to help., I also don't see anything relating to auto resizing the cell in IB.

Comment: The column resize is set by `[NSTableView columnAutoresizingStyle]` The text filed and it's should be controlled by that unless they are customized not to.

Comment: The tableView and column both already have autoresizes subviews enabled in IB. I'll try explicitly enabling it in my delegate init.

Comment: columnAutoresizingStyle only deals with how columns are automatically sized when the table is resized. I've tried changing it to autoresize the last column only, but it didn't help.

Comment: in addition, autoresizes subviews is on by default.